# Create unprivileged cgroups without root

Tags: linux, cgroups, linux-namespaces

I want to create cgroups inside new namespaces in order to control the
resource usage of processes as follows:

```
unshare --user --cgroup --mount --ipc --pid --net --uts -r --fork bash
mkdir -p my_cgroup/cpuset
mount -t cgroup -o cpuset cpuset ./my_cgroup/cpuset
```

But I cannot modify the cpuset folder as the folder's owner shows *nobody*.
Is there any way to set up cgroups in the new namespaces that I have 
permission to access ?